# bartMachine (Bayesian Additive Regression Tree) in >1 million cases in R

Tags: bayesian

I want to use BART via the bartMachine package for a dataframe of just over 1 million cases. With a lot of optimisation in the java memory setting, I can get R on my MacBook to complete the BART model for about 5000 cases. Anything above that is aborted as the system runs out of memory space.
Is there any chance I can use bartMachine() with an input matrix of 1 mio numbers of rows (ca. 15 predictors)?
Otherwise are there any alternative packages that would allow my to at least run predictor selection using BART?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to increase RAM option ? 
options(java.parameters="-Xmx12g") # must be set initially

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of this package. Have you tried "mem_cache_for_speed = FALSE" as an option?